# How can I add channel in an image array?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a numpy array with dimension `(10, 48, 48, 1)`. Here `10` represents number of images. Images are `48x48` with a single channel `1`. Since these are grayscale images  I want my array to to represent. Of course this is not possible but I want to initialize my other 2 channels with `0`. So How can I add other two dimension so that my array shape becomes `(10,48,48,3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `np.pad`

```
pad = ((0,0),)*3 + ((0,2),)
imgs = np.pad(imgs, pad, 'constant', constant_values = 0)
imgs.shape

(10, 288, 288, 3)
```

If instead of filling with zeros it's ok to repeat the values, you can also use `np.broadcast_to` (just be sure to make a copy if you want to write to it)

```
imgs = np.broadcast_to(imgs, (10, 48, 48, 3)).copy()
```

Answer (score 2):

Create the zeros array and concatenate along the last axis -

```
z = np.zeros(imgs.shape[:-1] + (2,), dtype=imgs.dtype)
imgs_out = np.concatenate((imgs, z), axis=-1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [157]: imgs = np.random.randint(0,255,(10,48,48,1)) # input

In [158]: z = np.zeros(imgs.shape[:-1] + (2,), dtype=imgs.dtype)

In [159]: np.concatenate((imgs, z), axis=-1).shape
Out[159]: (10, 48, 48, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use cv2.cvtcolor for it if you are using opencv
For eg:

```
img = np.zeros((255,255), dtype = np.uint8)
print(img.shape)
color_channeled_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
print(color_channeled_image.shape)
```

Your output:

```
(255,255)
(255,255,3)
```